# How to disable NFC EventListener when before second value read?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ionic-framework

This problem came from NFC tag is too sensitive.
When I put an NFC tag once, then too many values are entered momentarily.
So if one NFC tag value is entered, then wish to stop the NFC event listener at that moment. How do I implement it?

I think NFC reading speed is so fast in between device and NFC-tag than EventListener cancellation in program side.

**this ionic page working like this...**

*1) First load ionViewDidEnter()

2) Add addListenNFC()

3) If NFC tagged, then value send to onNfcLogin(tagId)

4) In onNfcLogin(tagId), this is included "Http post service provider" as userService.nfclogin()

5) Finally get the json type return from server side.*

**{
"dependencies": {
 "ionic-native/core": "4.7.0",
 "ionic-angular": "3.9.2", 
 "typescript": "~2.6.2"]
},
"test device": "Galaxy8",
"NFC Tag": "cheaped NFC stick"
}**

```
  ionViewDidEnter() {
    this.nfc.enabled().then((resolve) => {
      this.addListenNFC();
    }).catch((reject) => {
      alert("NFC is not supported by your Device");
    });
  }


  addListenNFC() {
    this.nfc.addTagDiscoveredListener().subscribe(data => {
    //window.removeEventListener; //this is not working.
      if (data && data.tag && data.tag.id) {
        this.tagId = this.nfc.bytesToHexString(data.tag.id);
        if (this.tagId) {
          this.scanned = true;
          this.onNfcLogin(this.tagId);
        } else {
          alert('NFC_NOT_DETECTED');
        }
      }
    });
  }


  onNfcLogin(tagId) {
    this.userService.nfclogin(tagId).subscribe(data => { 
       // "this.userService.nfclogin()" is at Http post service provider
      this.getData = JSON.stringify(data);
      if (this.getData) {
        this.granted = true;
        this.loading.dismiss();
        this.events.publish('user:login');
        this.navCtrl.setRoot(HomePage);
      }
      this.resetScanData;
    },
      error => {
        this.loading.dismiss();
        this.showError(error);
      });
  }


  showError(error) {
    console.log(error);
    let alert = this.alertCtrl.create({
      title: 'Login Error',
      message: error.json().message,
      buttons: ['OK']
    });
    alert.present();
  }


  resetScanData() {
    this.granted = false;
    this.scanned = false;
    this.tagId = "";
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved with this code.

```
this.myListener = this.nfc.addNdefListener(() => {
   console.log(‘successfully attached ndef listener’);
},(err) => {
   console.log(‘error attaching ndef listener’, err);
}).subscribe((event) => {
  . . .
});

//remove listener
this.myListener.unsubscribe();
```

thanks to Avdm in Ionic forum.
https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/remove-listener-nfc-plugin/113393

Answer (score 1):

You can take only the first subscription with observable.take(1).subscribe(...) .
And then re-create a subscription later.